# In Nginx, it has to be autoindex or directory forbidden error?

Tags: error-handling, nginx

I kept getting "directory forbidden error" on image directory /images/upload.

By adding autoindex on that directory, I can remove this error. But I don't want people to see what are under that directory.

How do I remove this error?

Nginx config

```
server
{
  listen       80;
  server_name  www.no-dev.com;
  index        index.php index.html index.htm;
  root         /opt/www/no_web;

  location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
  {
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include       fastcgi.conf;
  }

  #location /images {
  #  autoindex on;
  #}

  location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
              add_header  Last-Modified: $date_gmt;
              expires 1y;
              access_log off;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|bmp|swf)$ {
              expires max;
              access_log off;
  }
  access_log logs/no-dev.log main;
}
```

Comment: So what are you trying to do? What behavior are you expecting when people navigate to `/images/uploads`

Comment: Good question. According to cobaco answer, I could use error page instead of autoindex.

Comment: No, @cobaco's answer did not cover all possibilities but just one. The answer to this question is: **no**. Autoindex, index, and 403 error are not the only possibilities. You can do what you want.                                                     
Look at my answer just after.

Answer (score 2):

Return an index page or a 403 error are not the sole alternatives for a directory. For example, sometimes, a 404 error is more appropriate. Especially when you want to hide a folder.

In this case, there is an elegant way to do whatever you want:

```
# Create a fictive location which does what you want (404 here) 
location /404/ {
    internal;
    return 404;
}


# Use this fictive location as a folder index. That's all.
index /404/;
```

The directory Index requests will be handled by the (fictive) '/404/' internal location and will result in a 404 error. Be aware that it's an *internal* location. **The client browser is not redirected** in any way. It just gets a 404 return code for his request.

Here, the 404 error is just an example. When you redirect to an internal location you can do whatever you want.

So instead of returning 403 error code, of using an autoindex or of trying to hide your problem with a fake page, you can do exactly what you expect :)

Answer (score 1):

you have the following set:

```
index        index.php index.html index.htm;
```

That means that when autoindex is off your webserver will for each request for a directory path:

1. look for an index.php in that directory, and return that if found
2. if an index.php was not found it will look for an index.html and return that
3. if an index.html is also not found it will return an index.htm
4. if that isn't found either it will return a 403

so if you want to avoid the 403 error page you need to set up either index.php, index.html or index htm in that directory.

Alternatively you could set `error_page 403 some_page.html;`  to return a 403 result that looks different.

Comment: Even though I set 403 error_page, I still get "directory forbidden" in error log when I try to visit /images/upload. Any way to ignore this - do not let it write the error log?

Comment: What @cobaco is saying is: Just create an empty index.php file in `/images/upload/`. e.g. `touch /images/upload/index.php`. Any future requests will just simply load that empty page.

Answer (score 0):

This will return 403 directory forbidden, without an error, for http://example.com/ only:

```
location = / {
    return 403;
}
```

So, in your case:

```
location = /images/upload/ {
    return 403;
}
```

This will return 403 directory forbidden, without an error, for the /images/upload/ directory only.